# How to inject filter in ModalService in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog

I am doing my work in Angular JS (1.x). I am creating a modal using ModalService.
Now I want to use some filters in my modal. How can I use that considering there will not be a separate controller for the same.

Below is the code for ModalService.js

```
angular.module('appServices').service('ModalService', ['$modal',
  function ($modal) {
    this.showModal = function (customModalOptions) {
      return this.show(customModalOptions);
    };

    this.createModalView = function(templateUrl, scopeFields) {
      // bind the data prior to creating the modal overlay
      function MyModalController($scope) {
        angular.forEach(scopeFields, function(value, key) {
          $scope[key] = value;
        });
      }

      MyModalController.$inject = ['$scope'];

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve here. But filters can be injected in services and directives as shown below

> For this, inject a dependency with the name `<filterName>Filter` into
>   your controller/service/directive. E.g. a filter called number is
>   injected by using the dependency `numberFilter`. The injected argument
>   is a function that takes the value to format as first argument, and
>   filter parameters starting with the second argument.

Source: [Angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) docs.

Answer (score 0):

Just inject [`$filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) and pass it your filter name

```
function ($filter, SomeService) {
    let data = SomeService.getData();
    $scope.filteredData = $filter('myFilter')(data);
}
```

if that doesn't work, use [`$injector`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

```
$injector.get('$filter')('myFilter')(data);
```